# Number of disjoint regions = number of intersections + 1

Tags: geometry

If I have N circles, where every circle intersects every other circle at 2 distinct points, then the number of disjoint regions equals the number of intersections + 1.

I would like to know if there is a nice intutive reasoning to why this is true.

edit: To clear up, every circle intersects every other circle and every pair of intersection points is unique. So you cannot have something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acrq9.jpg)

[image]

Comment: This isn't true if the circles are concurrent.

Comment: Doesn't this depend on how the circles overlap? I mean, [look at the 173 different ways 4 circles can overlap](https://nltw.xyz/the-173-ways-you-can-overlap-four-circles-image/).

Comment: @mathlander Yes but in my question, I said every circle intersects every other circle.

Comment: I have edited to clear up that every circle intersects every other circle. @Graviton, in your example every circle does not necessarily intersect every other circle.

Comment: The difficulty is that there is more than one way 4 or more circles can intersect every other circle. See the image I linked. It's hard to tell which obey your criteria, since they are complicated, but I conjecture the number of distinct regions differ depending on the configuration.

Comment: @Graviton I'm pretty sure it is always number of intersections + 1. I am pretty sure the answer to [this](https://openclimb.io/practice/p3/q10/) question relies on this fact. And I could not find a counter example either.

Comment: Why aren't you counting the region *outside* of the circles as well?  Have you heard of [Euler's Characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic)?  Have you heard of $|V|-|E|+|F|=2$ for planar graphs?  (*Note that the outer region is considered a face for the purposes of the linked page*)

Comment: [Do you consider this a valid configuration?](https://imgur.com/a/7wpuVYB). It has 5 intersections but 8 regions (excluding the external region). If not, then [Euler's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Euler's_formula) probably has something to do with it.

Comment: @Graviton "*every circle intersects every other* **at two** *distinct points*"  Your image has the top left intersecting the bottom right at only one point.

Comment: @Graviton no because every intersection point isn't unique to a pair of circles. In the case you have linked, all 4 circles intersect at a single point. Also what JMoravitz said is also true.

Comment: @JMoravitz oops! That's true. Okay, [how about this configuration?](https://imgur.com/a/a78dUSo). 6 Intersections, 10(+1) regions. Every circles intersects every other at two distinct points individually.

Comment: @Graviton 3 circles are intersecting at the top point. There should be maximum 2

Comment: Gotcha! Sorry, I don't mean to confuse anyone, or make it look like your question is not well-defined; just making sure I understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Think inductively. Suppose you have a configuration with $n$ circles and the right number of regions and intersections. Now add another circle. How many new intersections are there? How have new regions been created?

Start by drawing a fourth circle in your three circle picture.

**Edit** in response to comment.

Suppose the answer is right for $n$ circles. Imagine the next one. It meets each of the old circles twice, so there are $2n$ new intersections, all on the new circle. Those intersections divide the new circle into $2n$ arcs. Each of those arcs cuts an old region in two, so there are $2n$ new regions. That says the answer is right for $n+1$ circles.

You can get the result directly from Euler's formula:

Suppose there are $n$ circles. Each meets the other $n-1$ twice, so contains $2(n-1)$ vertices that cut it into that many arcs. The total count of arcs is thus $2n(n-1)$. The total count of vertices is half that since each vertex appears on two circles.  Then
$$
1 = V - E + F = n(n-1) - 2n(n-1) + F
$$
so
$$
F = 1 + n(n-1) = 1 + V.
$$

Comment: Hmm, this was the original problem I was trying to solve (What is the maximum number of regions we can create by adding a new circle). And I concluded that when you added a new circle, you would *always* increase the number of intersections by the number of existing circles. The number of new regions it creates, however, I could not find (without using the idenity we are trying to prove).

Comment: I am trying to say that, I have unfortunately already tried to find how many new regions it creates for some time and gotten nowhere.

Comment: Looking at how each arc cuts a region into 2 is exactly what I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Let $a_n$=Number of Regions for number of circle drawn till n step

Define $b_n$=Increment of number of regions from $a_{n-1}$ to $a_n$
Thus $b_{n+1}-b_{n}$ is actually constant because speed of increment does not depend on n as it means the new circle cuts each of the previous regions into 2, implying $b_n=2(n-1) $ thus But $b_n=a_{n}-a_{n-1}=2(n-1)$ thus Thus $a_n={n(n-1)}+1$

Now, for $n$  circles we get two distinct points for each pair of circle so total number of point is $2$$n\choose 2$$=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$   $\blacksquare$

N.B: This is a very philosophical argument think it deeply it took me about 4hrs to visualize.

Thanks to 60q for his comment!!!!

Comment: I don't understand why the speed of increment = how many points, pairs of circles intersect at.

Comment: @60q speed of increment is 2 it's because it's any circle drawn divides each previous region in 2, I must edit that Thanks. I hope this makes sense now.